# How to implement a sort within the confines of a vector?

Tags: c, sorting, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been tasked with writing a pseudo-vector with dynamic memory allocation in C. I've been mostly successful but there's a bonus part that requests us to implement a sort function of our choice. Just to see if I could get the indexing and such correctly, I went with bubble sort, however I've been entirely unsuccessful in this. I assume it's due to how I'm passing my vector struct into the function but it seems like I'm accessing the wrong data. I'll be adding my (unsuccessful) attempt at a swap function using the vector type as well. I'd like someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

This is homework, if that wasn't explicit already. I tried adding the correct tag but it seems it doesn't exist here.

vec.c

```
#include "vec.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define GOOD 0;
#define BAD -1;

struct SVec VecInit(void) {
    struct SVec vec;
    vec.pData = 0;
    vec.uiCount = 0;

    return vec;
}

int VecAdd(struct SVec * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int newsz = vec->uiCount + 1;
    if (vec->pData == 0)
        vec->pData = (int*)malloc(newsz * sizeof(int));
    else
        vec->pData = (int*)realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(int));

    *(vec->pData + vec->uiCount) = iVal;
    vec->uiCount++;

    return 1;
}

int VecContains(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int index;
    if (iVal < 0) return BAD;
    for (index = 0; index < vec->uiCount; index++) {
        if (*(vec->pData + index) == iVal) {
            return GOOD; //success, change later
        }
    }
    return BAD; //fail, change later
}

int VecDie(struct SVec * const vec) {
    free(vec->pData);
    vec->pData = NULL;
    vec->uiCount = 0;
    //free(vec); //not sure if this is necessary
}

int VecGet(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index) {
    if (index > vec->uiCount || vec->uiCount <= 0 || index < 0)
        return BAD; //failure
    return vec->pData[index];
}

int VecIndexAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int index;
    if (!VecContains(&vec, iVal))
        return BAD; //value wasn't found
    for (index = 0; index < vec->uiCount; index++) {
        if (*(vec->pData + index) == iVal)
            return index;
    }

    return BAD; //value wasn't found, should not be able to get here but let's be explicit
}

int VecRemove2(struct SVec * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int newsize = vec->uiCount - 1;
    int start;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->uiCount; i++) {
        if (*(vec->pData + i) == iVal) {
            *(vec->pData + i) = NULL;
            start = i;
            for (start; start < vec->uiCount; start++) {
                if (start + 1 >= vec->uiCount) break; //bound check the end of vector
                *(vec->pData + start) = *(vec->pData + start + 1);
            }
            vec->pData = (int*)realloc(vec->pData, newsize * sizeof(int));
            vec->uiCount--;
            return GOOD;
        }
    }

    return BAD;
}

int VecRemove(struct SVec * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int newsz = vec->uiCount - 1;
    int indexToRemove;
    int index;

    if (vec->uiCount == 0) { return BAD; }

    if (!VecContains(&vec, iVal)) { return BAD; }
    else {
        indexToRemove = VecIndexAt(&vec, iVal);
        *(vec->pData + indexToRemove + 1) = NULL;

        for (index = 0; index < sizeof(vec[0]) / sizeof(vec); index++) {
            if (index == 0) continue;
            vec->pData[index] = vec->pData[index + 1];
        }

        //vec->pData = (int*)realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(int));
        vec->uiCount--;
        return GOOD;
    }
}

int VecSet(struct SVec * const vec, int const index, int const iVal) {
    if (!VecContains(&vec, iVal) || index > vec->uiCount || index < 0) return BAD;
    vec->pData[index] = iVal;
}

int VecShow(struct SVec const * const vec) {
    int count = vec->uiCount;
    int index;

    if (vec->uiCount == 0) return -1;

    for (index = 0; index <= count; index++) {
        if (index == count - 1) {
            printf("%d", *(vec->pData + index));
            break;
        }
        printf("%d, ", *(vec->pData + index));
    }

    printf("\n");
}

//does not work
void VecShuffle(struct SVec * const vec, int const size) {
    int i, j, tmp;

    for (i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = rand() % (i + 1);
        tmp = VecGet(&vec, j);
        VecSet(&vec, j, VecGet(&vec, i));
        VecSet(&vec, i, tmp);
    }
}

int VecSize(struct SVec const * const vec) {
    return vec->uiCount;
}

//does not work
void VecSort(struct SVec * vec) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < vec->uiCount - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vec->uiCount - i - 1; j++) {
            if (VecGet(&vec, j) > VecGet(&vec, j + 1)) {
                int temp = VecGet(&vec, i);
                int iValIndex = VecIndexAt(&vec, i);
                int jValIndex = VecIndexAt(&vec, j);
                VecSet(&vec, iValIndex, i);
                VecSet(&vec, jValIndex, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

//REMOVE LATER
int VecValueAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index) {
    if (index > vec->uiCount || vec->uiCount <= 0 || index < 0)
        return BAD; //failure
    return *(vec->pData + index);
}

//does not work
void VecSwap(struct SVec * vec, int const iVal, int const jVal) {
    int temp = VecGet(&vec, iVal);
    int iValIndex = VecIndexAt(&vec, iVal);
    int jValIndex = VecIndexAt(&vec, jVal);
    VecSet(&vec, iValIndex, iVal);
    VecSet(&vec, jValIndex, temp);

}

void main() {
    struct SVec vec = VecInit();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        VecAdd(&vec, i);
    }

    VecShow(&vec);

    //VecSort(&vec);

    VecShow(&vec);

    getchar();
}
```

vec.h

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

struct SVec
{
    int  *pData;
    uint uiCount;
};

struct SVec VecInit(void);

int VecAdd(struct SVec const * vec, int const iVal);

int VecContains(struct SVec const const * vec, int const iVal);

int VecDie(struct SVec const * vec);

int VecGet(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index);

int VecIndexAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal);

int VecRemove(struct SVec const * vec, int const iVal);

int VecRemove2(struct SVec const * vec, int const iVal);

int VecSet(struct SVec * const vec, int const index, int const iVal);

int VecShow(struct SVec const * const vec);

void VecShuffle(struct SVec * const vec, int const size);

int VecSize(struct SVec const * const vec);

void VecSort(struct SVec * const vec);

int VecValueAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index);
```

When I could get the function to work, it wouldn't have any effect on the vector, which is what made me think about the struct passing issue. Now the program won't compile if I use VecSort() and I don't recall what I changed.

Updated the code to reflect some changes mentioned and for completeness, prototypes and header file.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the examples are right there. i don't have any errors because the code doesn't work. i don't know what more i can post

Comment: The code you posted uses things called `VecGet`, `VecSet`, and `VecIndexAt` but does not show definitions of them. It is not complete and will not compile. You must provide complete code that will compile. In addition to doing that, unless the program runs without any input, you must show sample input. And you should state clearly what the program **does do**, such as print the wrong output (show it) or crash, and what you would like the program to do instead (show the correct output).

Comment: The short version is "Post something I can copy/paste and compile to help me help you with your question".

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for that, didn't even notice. I'll post those now.

Comment: `VecAdd`? It does realloc?

Comment: Yes, I've added that as well. I'll just post all my code next time. I was trying to be concise and really just screwed everything up.

Comment: Note that `realloc(NULL, ...` is equal to `malloc(...)` so there is no need for the `if(vec->pData==0)` inside `VecAdd`

Comment: Noted. Do you mind explaining that a little further? I don't fully understand.

Comment: There is no `main`, so this is not a complete program. The code uses `printf` without including `<stdio.h>`. The code uses a type `uint` without defining it. There should not be a semicolon at the end of `#define GOOD 0;`. The functions `VecGet`, `VecIndexAt`, `VecSet`, and `VecContains` should be declared before they are used (this may be done by putting their definitions before their uses). The `Vec*` functions generally take a `struct SVec *`, but they are passed `&vec` where `vec` is already a `struct SVec *`, so they are passed a `struct SVec **`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron what part don't you understand? If `pData == 0` that means that `pData = NULL`. You can call `realloc(pData, new_size)`. If `pData == NULL` then `realloc(pData, ...)` willl be equal to calling `malloc()`. So you can get rid of the `if` statement, and just `realloc(pData,  ...)`, because if `pData == NULL` it will call `malloc` the same as if the `if` is true.

Comment: You want me to post function prototypes?

Comment: `VecShow` contains `return -1;` but is declared `void`, so it cannot return a value. `VecSet` has a path on which it does not return a value but is declared to return `int`, so it likely ought to return a value. This is technically not an error per the C standard since none of the code shown uses a return value from `VecSet`, but it is not good practice.

Comment: Your `VecSwap` is strange. You shouldn't swap the indices with certain values in the array. You know the indices from `VecGet(&vec, j) > VecGet(&vec, j + 1)`. You want to swap element at index `j` with element at index `j + 1` right?

Comment: Fix the errors I have described and post code that actually compiles. You wrote in the question that “it seems like I'm accessing the wrong data”, which sounds like you actually ran the program. Did you compile and run the program? I do not see how given the code in the question—that code will not compile at least because of the `return -1` in `VecShow` and the use of `uint` without a definition. Or maybe your comment about “accessing the wrong data” is just confusion about compiler error messages?

Comment: @Eric Several of the things you've listed were omitted because I was trying to be concise I wrongly assumed that others would assume they were in the code, such as the `unsigned int` typedef and the `#include <stdio.h>`. II'll know for next time to be more explicit and thorough.

Comment: A [mcve] is **complete**: “Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**” … ”**Make sure it's complete**” … “Copy the code from your question into a new file or project, then run it. If it doesn't run for you, then it won't run for anyone else.”

Comment: @Eric The program did run and I've been messing with it for the last several hours, going from broken to working but improper results. I guess this happened to be one of the broken times. Also, the return in VecShow has never given me an error in the past - I've fixed it now because it's obviously bad practice though.

Comment: The address of operator `&` usage is invalid in your functions. Listen to compiler warnings. Fix all compiler warnings, and you have many of them. Inside `VecSet(struct SVec * const vec` the variable `vec` is already a pointer. You are passing the address of the pointer to `VecContains(&vec, iVal)`. You should `VecContains(vec, iVal)`, as you already have the pointer value. The same count's for all the functions you use. | Also isn't `vec->pData[index]` more readable then `*(vec->pData + index)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree it is much more readable but my professor suggested we use pointer arithmetic more to get used to it. I don't agree but I need the marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

#define GOOD 0
#define BAD  ( assert(0), -1 )

struct SVec
{
    int  *pData;
    uint uiCount;
};

void VecShow(struct SVec const * const vec);
int VecAdd(struct SVec * const vec, int const iVal);
void VecSwap(struct SVec * vec, int const iVal, int const jVal);
int VecSet(struct SVec * const vec, int const index, int const iVal);
int VecIndexAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal);
int VecGet(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index);
int VecContains(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal);


int VecAdd(struct SVec * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int newsz = vec->uiCount + 1;
    if (vec->pData == 0)
        vec->pData = (int*)malloc(newsz * sizeof(int));
    else
        vec->pData = (int*)realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(int));

    *(vec->pData + vec->uiCount) = iVal;
    vec->uiCount++;

    return 1;
}

void VecShow(struct SVec const * const vec) {
    int count = vec->uiCount;
    int index;

    if (vec->uiCount == 0) return;

    for (index = 0; index <= count; index++) {
        if (index == count - 1) {
            printf("%d", *(vec->pData + index));
            break;

        }
        printf("%d, ", *(vec->pData + index));
    }

    printf("\n");
}


void VecSwap(struct SVec * vec, int const iVal, int const jVal) {
    int temp = VecGet(vec, iVal);
    int iValIndex = VecIndexAt(vec, iVal);
    int jValIndex = VecIndexAt(vec, jVal);
    VecSet(vec, iValIndex, iVal);
    VecSet(vec, jValIndex, temp);

}

int VecSet(struct SVec * const vec, int const index, int const iVal) {
    if (!VecContains(vec, iVal) || index > vec->uiCount || index < 0) return BAD;
    vec->pData[index] = iVal;
}

int VecIndexAt(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int index;
    if (!VecContains(vec, iVal))
        return BAD; //value wasn't found
    for (index = 0; index < vec->uiCount; index++) {
        if (*(vec->pData + index) == iVal)
            return index;
    }

    return BAD; //value wasn't found, should not be able to get here but let's be explicit
}

int VecContains(struct SVec const * const vec, int const iVal) {
    int index;
    if (iVal < 0) return BAD;
    for (index = 0; index < vec->uiCount; index++) {
        if (*(vec->pData + index) == iVal) {
            return GOOD;
        }
    }
    return BAD;
}

int VecGet(struct SVec const * const vec, int const index) {
    if (index > vec->uiCount || vec->uiCount <= 0 || index < 0)
        return BAD; //failure
    return vec->pData[index];
}

void VecSort(struct SVec * vec) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < vec->uiCount - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < vec->uiCount - i - 1; j++) {
            if (VecGet(vec, j) > VecGet(vec, j + 1)) {
                int tmp = vec->pData[j];
                vec->pData[j] = vec->pData[j + 1];
                vec->pData[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct SVec vec = {0};
    for (size_t i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        VecAdd(&vec, i);
    }
    VecShow(&vec);
    VecSort(&vec);
    VecShow(&vec);
    // leak memory
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1                                                                                                              
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

1. In your code you misuse the `&` address of operator, as you apply it to pointers. Example in `void VecSwap(struct SVec * vec, int const iVal, int const jVal) {
   int temp = VecGet(&vec, iVal);` - the `&vec` is the address of `struct SVec * vec` *pointer* (not the data!), so you are passing to the `VecGet` function a `struct SVec **` pointer, ie. a pointer to a pointer to the data. It makes the code invalid in multiple places. The compiler shouldn't at least warn you about that.
2. In your sorting function after you compare elements at indexes `j` and `j + 1` you want to swap elements at that indexes. Not elements that are storing the value of `j` (which could be at any index, or ever none), but the elements exactly at index `j` and `j + 1`.
3. It makes no point in `return BAD` if `#define BAD -1`. How am I going to store minus one in the array? Is `-1` a significant number? Usually programmers choose the maximum (INT_MAX) or minimum value (INT_MIN) for returning an error, or they return `0` and also set a global flag (looking at you `strtol`...)
4. The part:

   ```
   if (vec->pData == 0)
       vec->pData = (int*)malloc(newsz * sizeof(int));
   else
       vec->pData = (int*)realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(int));
   ```

   could be simplified to just:

   ```
   vec->pData = realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(int));
   ```

   `realloc(NULL, ...)` is equal to calling `malloc(...)`. And `0` is implicitly convertible to `NULL`, as `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` (let's not dwell into that more...)
5. I've seen much of `*(arr + index)` syntax over the years, but I don't think it has any justification here. You are indexing an array, just `arr[index]` which is exactly equivalent (and please don't `index[arr]`)
6. `const struct SVec *` looks nicer and more common to me than `struct SVec const *`.
7. As noted by @Eric - the `void VecShow(...)` function contains `return -1` which is at least undefined behavior and I was surprised to find out it actually compiled on the archaic gcc version I used.
8. It would be nice to include allocation error checking. Usually when using `realloc` the proper way is to use a temporary pointer.

   ```
   void * const tmp = realloc(vec->pData, newsz * sizeof(*vec->pData));
   if (tmp == NULL) {
       // the old pointer vec->pData is still valid!
       return BAD;
    }
    // success
    vec->pData = tmp;
   ```
9. Except for those errors this looks like very good code with good encapsulation and organisation. The structure is nice, there are `const` pointers when needed, good indentation, many checks, very readable, nice. And sorry for my still not perfect English.

Comment: What's the leak memory for at the end? Because I didn't call `VecDie()`?

Comment: I know nothing about `VecDie()` function.

Comment: It's there. You probably didn't see because I've edited several times but I posted all the functions and prototypes, typedefs, whatever there is, it's there now.

Comment: `#define BAD  ( assert(0), -1 )` Why this change?

Comment: So I catch when something bad happens. I don't care about writing proper error handling code for simple stackoverflow code snippets - I just insert an assertion. I wanted to catch the cases when `VecGet` returns `BAD`. Right now the code just `return -1` so it is impossible to catch the error (as the aray stores `int` type, `-1` is a valid value....)

Comment: Gotcha. I'll start using that instead of doing `printf` to see the return value, haha.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron Kamil Cuk did a whale of a job. You don't may much attention to your compiler warnings do you? [212 Lines of Compilers Errors/Warnings in Original Code](http://susepaste.org/34758870). Let your compiler help you write better code.

Comment: Truth be told, David, I'm new to Visual Studio and the error tab was hidden. I'm fixing the warnings now.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron - yep, I was never to hip on the VS IDE for small projects. "Projects" are a PITA for just a couple of files and the IDE hides what is really taking place. Far easier just to open the `VS Developers Command Prompt` and build/run right from the command line (in any directory you like). I generally just create a source directory (e.g. srcc) and then `obj` and `bin` sub-directories to keep things tidy. Then to compile it is simply `cl /nologo /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/ /Febin/yourexename /Tc yoursource.c` (`cl.exe` is the VS compiler, `/wd4996` gets rid of the `4996` warning `:)`

Comment: Just type `cl /?` for all the options. Life will get much simpler (and faster) and then you will know exactly what option you want to use to compile and can then tell the IDE how you want it done (instead of the other way around)

Comment: Oh man, that's so nice to know. I learned C/C++ on Linux in vim with gcc so I feel more comfortable in this environment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it bad form to ask another question here which is very related but still another question? Or should I make another one?

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron Another question is another question. General rule: One question per question ^^ btw. Next time you ask a question about "not working" code you should probably provide a [mcve] that only consists of one file.